# Root or non-root of a pthread

Tags: pthreads

Is it possible to check if the owner of a thread (with a pthread id) is a root user or a non-root user? From what I searched in internet, there seems to be no direct way exists to obtain the owner information. (For current thread, I know we can make use of getuid() calls. But my interest on to get the information for other threads).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thread runs in the same process as the code that started it with pthread_create().  Don't confuse threads with processes, fork(), etc.  Unless your program is calling one of the setuid() family of functions, it should be exactly the same as it is in main().

**EDIT:** based on new information below.

There is no standard way of querying a separate process about its threads or their root status using the pthread_* interface.  It might be possible on a particular platform to examine OS-specific process information to obtain that data, but no portable way. Also, you don't mention what platform you are running this on, or if it needs to work cross-platform.

You could possibly use some other method of IPC to query the threaded app (if you can modify it as well) and ask it directly if it is running as root.  The threaded app would have to be changed to keep track of all of its threads, their tid's, etc. to answer a question the way you describe it below.  You will still need to make sure the IPC mechanism you chose is also portable to the supported platforms.

Still, a pthread thread ID from one process is of very little value to another process by itself.  You should think carefully about what you are really trying to accomplish and ask a question with enough details to cover the real goal.

Comment: its mistake on my part for I did not mention that I wanted to obtain the root or non-root information of the pthreads of altogether a different process. I know the threads in a process have same owner info (unless setuid*() used). I was interested in obtaining this owner info irrespective of whether the thread belongs to the same process or different one. Basically I was looking forward for a function like this (as this is my requirement).
int is_owner_root(pthread_t tid)
{    
if(owner_of_tid(tid) == ROOT) return 1;    
else    
return 0;    
}